# Power of Repeated-Measures ANOVA vs Mixed-Effects Model

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, statistical-power

I am interested in whether a mixed-effects model yields more power than a repeated measures ANOVA and why.

A fried of mine wrote this in an email the other day and I found it striking.

"Repeated-measures ANOVA does not account for random effects. It treats everyone in the same cell in a factorial design the same. Any residual error goes into the SS(error) hence this accounting for subject-level variance should decrease the MSerror in a mixed-effects model and increase its power over a repeated-measures ANOVA."

Is this passage true? Are mixed-effect models more powerful, and, if so, is this because they account for more of the Error variance than repeated-measures ANOVA?

Comment: In a repeated-measures ANOVA, "subjects" is a random effect. That's why the error term for Treatments is the Treatments x Subjects interaction.

Comment: Thank you @David Lane. What about mixed-effects models explaining more variance than repeated-measures ANOVA?

Comment: I've always viewed repeated measures ANOVA as a mixed effect model since it has a mixture of fixed and random effects.

Comment: So @David Lane you're saying that not only are mixed-effects models *not* more powerful than repeated-measures ANOVA, they are exactly the same?

Comment: ANOVA restricts you to one random factor (subjects) whereas mixed models can have multiple random factors.

Comment: Thanks @David Lane, very illuminating. I read something similar in Barr et al.'s *Keeping it Maximal* paper but then I read other things that raised doubts. If you put it in an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a repeated-measures ANOVA, "subjects" is a random effect. That's why the error term for Treatments is the Treatments x Subjects interaction. ANOVA restricts you to one random factor (subjects) whereas mixed models can have multiple random factors.